# Can not install ia32-libs in Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: apt, package-management

when I try to install `ia32-libs` I got this error:

```
asdfg@notebook:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 adduser : Depends: passwd (>= 1:4.0.12)
           Recommends: ecryptfs-utils (>= 67-1) but it is not going to be installed
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
 openssh-client : Depends: passwd
 procps : Depends: initscripts
 upstart : Depends: initscripts
           Depends: mountall
           Depends: ifupdown (>= 0.6.10ubuntu5)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

When I try to install `ia32-libs-multiarch` :

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: bluez-alsa:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgettextpo0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gtk2-engines:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gvfs:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ibus-gtk:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libacl1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libao4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libasound2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libasyncns0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libattr1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libaudio2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libcap2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libcapi20-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libcupsimage2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libcurl3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libesd0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgail-common:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgconf-2-4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgdbm3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386
                            Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgphoto2-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgphoto2-port0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgtk2.0-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libmpg123-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libncursesw5:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libnspr4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libnss3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libopenal1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-network:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-opengl:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-qt3support:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-script:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-scripttools:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-sql:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-svg:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-test:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-xml:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqtcore4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqtgui4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: librsvg2-common:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libsdl-mixer1.2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libsdl-image1.2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libsdl-net1.2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libsdl1.2debian:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libsqlite3-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libssl0.9.8:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libstdc++5:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libstdc++6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libxaw7:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libxml2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libxp6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libxss1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libxtst6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: odbcinst1debian2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libpulsedsp:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: xaw3dg:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
                            Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

Output of `sudo apt-get check` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

How can I fix it ?
I use Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit .

Comment: Why you need the ia32-libs package? Could you edit your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get check`?

Comment: @ Braiam, Thanks a lot for your answer. I need it for android development Tools (ADT). The output added ;)

Comment: Which? I see 64-bits bundles everywhere. ATD and only SDK has 64-bits version, why are you trying to use 32bits? http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Install both the ia32-libs-multiarch and the ia32-libs at the same time.  If that fails, purge the ia32-libs you installed, and then try the two packges together.

Comment: unfortunately didn't worked .